# How to exExtract list values within xml elements using PHP

Tags: php, xml, list, xpath

In my xml file I have the following...

```
 <fieldcontent><![CDATA[<ul><li><a href='http://www.mysite1.com/'>My Site 1</a></li>
      <li><a href='http://wwwmysite2.com'>My Site 2</a></li>
      <li><a href='http://wwwmysite3.com'>My Site 3</a></li>
      </ul>]]></fieldcontent>
```

Using xpath or simplexml in php how can i extract the ahref label part (i.e. 'My Site 1') within each

tag and do stuff with each value?

Note, the number of

tags can vary from one to ?

Many Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Actually you likely will not be able to do both actions in one step. You likely will need to parse the XML first, receive the content of `fieldcontent`, and parse it again as a new tree (which it actually is) or use regular expressions to extract the data you want.

Comment: I actually need to extract the values and add them to a new xml using DOM createElement and appendChild so my new xml will look like..


<fieldcontent>My Site 1</fieldcontent>

<fieldcontent>My Site 2</fieldcontent>

<fieldcontent>My Site 3</fieldcontent>

Comment: `//a/text()` doesn't work for you?

Comment: How would I implement '//a/text()'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is an html fragment inside an xml text node (a cdata node).

So first read the html into a string:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$html = $xpath->evaluate('string(//fieldcontent)');

var_dump($html);
```

Output:

```
string(176) "<ul><li><a href='http://www.mysite1.com/'>My Site 1</a></li>
<li><a href='http://wwwmysite2.com'>My Site 2</a></li>
<li><a href='http://wwwmysite3.com'>My Site 3</a></li>
</ul>"
```

Now that you have the html you can load it into a DOM and look for the li/a elements:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//li/a') as $link) {
  var_dump(
    $link->getAttribute('href'), 
    $link->nodeValue
  );
}
```

Output:

```
string(23) "http://www.mysite1.com/"
string(9) "My Site 1"
string(21) "http://wwwmysite2.com"
string(9) "My Site 2"
string(21) "http://wwwmysite3.com"
string(9) "My Site 3"
```

Live example: https://eval.in/122690